# How do I write a full outer join query in access

Tags: sql, ms-access

Original query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM AA
FULL OUTERJOIN BB on (AA.C_ID = BB.C_ID);
```

How do I convert the query above to make it compatible in Microsoft Access?

I am assuming:

```
SELECT *
FROM AA
FULL LEFT JOIN BB ON (AA.C_ID = BB.C_ID);
```

I haven't dealt with the "FULL" criteria before am I correctly converting the first query into a query compatible with Access?

Answer (score 38):

Assuming there are not duplicate rows in AA and BB (i.e. all the same values), a full outer join is the equivalent of the union of a left join and a right join.

```
SELECT *
    FROM AA
        LEFT JOIN BB ON AA.C_ID = BB.C_ID
UNION
SELECT *
    FROM AA
        RIGHT JOIN BB ON AA.C_ID = BB.C_ID
```

If there are duplicate rows (and you want to keep them), add `WHERE AA.C_ID IS NULL` at the end, or some other field that is only null if there is not corresponding record from AA.

EDIT:

See a similar approach [here](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/msaccess/article.php/3516561/Implementing-the-Equivalent-of-a-FULL-OUTER-JOIN-in-Microsoft-Access.htm).

It recommends the more verbose, but more performant

```
SELECT *
    FROM AA
        JOIN BB ON AA.C_ID = BB.C_ID
UNION ALL
SELECT *
    FROM AA
        LEFT JOIN BB ON AA.C_ID = BB.C_ID
    WHERE BB.C_ID IS NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT *
    FROM AA
        RIGHT JOIN BB ON AA.C_ID = BB.C_ID
    WHERE AA.C_ID IS NULL
```

However, this assumes that `AA.C_ID` and `BB.C_ID` are not null.

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to just use `UNION ALL` instead of `WHERE` clauses?

Comment: Good Answer+ except the second example doesn't work as-is in Access. I changed the first `JOIN` to `INNER JOIN` and it seems to do what it's supposed to.

Answer (score 13):

The more eficient and faster code:

```
SELECT *
    FROM AA
        LEFT JOIN BB ON AA.C_ID = BB.C_ID
UNION ALL
SELECT *
    FROM AA
        RIGHT JOIN BB ON AA.C_ID = BB.C_ID
    WHERE AA.C_ID IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

I found that if the field names are the same in both tables they will need to be listed individually rather than using the * operator.  Also, the second SELECT statement needs to reference the other table. Simply using the same SQL as the first and changing it to a RIGHT JOIN does not allow the inclusion of the rows in the BB table.

```
SELECT AA.C_ID
FROM AA
LEFT JOIN BB ON 
  AA.C_ID = BB.C_ID
UNION ALL 
SELECT BB.C_ID
FROM BB
LEFT JOIN AA ON 
  AA.C_ID = BB.C_ID
WHERE AA.C_ID IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Or... You could create a query with unique records on the field that you need:

```
SELECT DISTINCT AA.C_ID
FROM AA
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT BB.C_ID
FROM BB;
```

And with that query you can do a left join with both of the tables on "C_ID"