# Display blank(null/empty) values in ms access

Tags: sql, ms-access, null

I have a database in MS Access, and I ran into a problem with empty values. I have 3 tables that are connected to eachother. Lets say Table1 contains people, Table 2 contains Phone numbers, and Table 3 connects table 1 and 2, having both their ID's so I could later see what person has what numbers by using the IDs.

What I want from access is that it would display a person even if he/she doesn't have a number assigned, and also a number when there are no people assigned to it.

Something like this:

```
Persons_name |Phone_number
--------------------------
Fred         |    123
             |    222
Anna         |
```

The tables look something like this:

```
People                People_phones         Phones
-------------         --------------        ------------
ID                    ID                    ID
Persons_name          People_ID             Phone_number
                      Phones_ID
```

So far I've managed to get access to show either table 1's null values or table 2's null values, but not both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As E Mett indicated above, your looking for a full outer join which doesn't handle directly.  Here is an example of what he's suggesting:

[How do I write a full outer join query in access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19615177/how-do-i-write-a-full-outer-join-query-in-access)

JB

Comment: Thank you both, as soon as I can get back to Access I will try these, and confirm an answer to this question

Answer (score 1):

In `sql` jargon what you are looking for is an `outer join`.

This is unfortunately not available in `Ms Access` because it is rarely needed.

You should create two queries, one using a `left join` and the other with a `right join`.

Then use the `UNION` keyword to combine the results