# How to compare two fields and return the matching result but also the semi matching result

Tags: sql, ms-access

so i've got two fields in two tables

```
us                       them
entity|currency|amount   entity|currency|amount
purple| usd    | 7.00    purple|usd     |7.00
purple| usd    | 2.00    purple|usd     |1.00
purple| huf    | 1.00
```

Entity has a company name and currency is a currency code like usd or huf and amount is a dollar amount.

right now i'm joining them on entity and currency and summing the instances of that currency for the particular entity then creating another column in the result to find the difference.

so right now, the way i'm doing it, i'll get

```
entity| currency | ussum | themsum | differ
purple| usd      | 9.00  | 8.00    | 1.00
```

But it will omit the purple huf because it doesn't exist on the other table.  i'm trying to figure out how to get all the currencies that don't exist on either side even if they don't exist on the other side.

Comment: Where is your SQL code to get the current results?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19615177/how-do-i-write-a-full-outer-join-query-in-access

Comment: Note: If you have a "master currency table" with an entry for each currency type, joining that first, then left joining in both data tables alleviates the need for a "full outer join".  (Since the master table should already contain all valid currencies)