# SQL. Combining two queries with aggregate functions and WHERE conditions

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am relatively new to SQL and ran into a problem I can't seem to solve. I am using Access and I tried to work something with IIF, but that doesn't help or I don't know how.

I have got 2 queries that work fine on their own, how can I combine them into one? My biggest problem seems to be to me that I have two WHERE statements that I cannot seem to get into one query.

```
SELECT CODE, SUM(Costs)/SUM(Quantity) AS SIMPLE_COST_BASE 
FROM Shares 
WHERE EVENT = 'Buy' 
GROUP BY CODE;
```

```
SELECT CODE, (SUM(Costs) + SUM(DRP_PAY))/SUM(Quantity) AS NORMAL_COST_BASE 
FROM Shares 
WHERE EVENT <> 'Sell' 
GROUP BY CODE;
```

My desired result is a table with three columns. One for CODE, one for the SIMPLE_COST_BASE and a third for NORMAL_COST_BASE

Comment: Please add some example data and your expected result. And I think you can use `UNION` ;).

Comment: Sorry shA.t, you can see I am a beginner :)

Comment: Try a union of the queries.

Answer (score 1):

I think something like this should work:

```
SELECT Shares.CODE, Sum(IIf([EVENT]<>"Buy",[Costs]/[Quantity],0)) AS SIMPLE_COST_BASE,
Sum(IIf([EVENT]<>"Sell",[DRP_PAY]/[Quantity],0)) AS NORMAL_COST_BASE
FROM Shares
GROUP BY Shares.CODE;
```

Comment: Thanks Sergey. Unfortunately, the values calculated don't seem right. I am not quite sure why and am still trying to understand it.

Comment: If you give an example of data and expected result, we will find why it doesn't work as expected.

Comment: Thanks Sergey, these are some example rows  
  
CODE / EVENT / Quantity  / COSTS / DRP-Pay  
CCV; Buy; 1000; 965; 0  
CCV; Buy, 1800; 1980; 0  
CCV; DRP; 60; 0; 55.80  
CCV; DRP; 53; 0; 56.99  
CCV; DRP; 65; 0; 58.50  
  
The values I would be expecting for the three columns are:    
CODE: CCV  
SIMPLE_COST_BASE: 1.0517  
NORMAL_COST_BASE: 0.9889

Answer (score 0):

If it is certain that both queries will return the same number of rows with the same codes (both return "all" codes), you can simply JOIN them as subqueries:

```
SELECT buy.CODE, buy.SIMPLE_COST_BASE, notsell.NORMAL_COST_BASE
FROM
(
    (SELECT CODE, SUM(Costs)/SUM(Quantity) AS SIMPLE_COST_BASE 
    FROM Shares 
    WHERE EVENT = 'Buy' 
    GROUP BY CODE) AS buy

    INNER JOIN

    (SELECT CODE, (SUM(Costs) + SUM(DRP_PAY))/SUM(Quantity) AS NORMAL_COST_BASE 
    FROM Shares 
    WHERE EVENT <> 'Sell' 
    GROUP BY CODE) AS notsell

    ON buy.CODE = notsell.CODE
)
```

If some codes may be in only one of the query result sets, you should save both subqueries as separate Access queries, and then do a FULL OUTER JOIN simulation of them with the technique described here: [How do I write a full outer join query in access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19615177/how-do-i-write-a-full-outer-join-query-in-access)