# Select distinct record with join count records

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two tables: **Company** and **Contact**,  with a relationship of one-to-many.
I have another table **Track** which identifies some of the companies as parent companies to other companies. 
[image]

I want to write a SQL query that selects the parent companies from Track and the amount of contacts that each parent has.

```
SELECT Track.ParentId, Count(Contact.companyId) 
FROM Track     
    INNER JOIN Contact
    ON Track.ParentId = Contact.companyId
GROUP BY Track.ParentId
```

however The result holds less records than when I run the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Track.ParentId
FROM Track
```

I tried the first query with an added `DISTINCT` and it returned the same results (less then what it was meant to).

Comment: read https://mattmazur.com/2017/11/01/counting-in-mysql-when-joins-are-involved/

Answer (score 4):

You're performing an `INNER JOIN` with the Contact table, which means that any rows from the first table (Track in this case) with no matches to the `JOIN`ed table will not show up in your results. Try using a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` instead.

The `COUNT` with `Contact.companyId` will only count rows where there is a match (`Contact.companyId` is not `NULL`). Since you're counting contacts that's fine as they will count as 0. If you were trying to count some other set of data and tried to do a `COUNT` on a specific column (rather than `COUNT(*)`) then any `NULL` values in that column would not count towards your total, which might or might not be what you want.

Comment: Looks good, in addition however, if rosa wants 0 or null counts, may need to adjust count using coalese or case or isnull or other variations to return 0 instead of null. perhaps `coalesce(count(contact.companyID)) as cnt`

Comment: Yes, depending on what the specific requirements are that might be necessary. Good point.

Comment: I can't use left outer join, because I'm using access, but the answer I found is similar. Thanks.

Comment: @xQbert, Can any one elaborate on the 0 or null remark? I didn't understand. Remember- I'm using ms-access

Comment: I've added an explanation of COUNT with NULL values. Hopefully it's clear enough.

Comment: @rosa  msaccess supports [left, right joins](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208894(v=office.12).aspx)  FULL outer must be [simulated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19615177/how-do-i-write-a-full-outer-join-query-in-access) using left and right joins along with a union .

Answer (score 0):

I used an INNER JOIN which returns only records that are identical in both tables.

To return **all** records from Track table, and records that match in the Contact table, I need to use LEFT JOIN.