# Syntax error in FROM clause. (Error 3131)

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

I used Access to construct this query by default it uses an inner join, but when I change it to outer I get this error. Any ideas? Thanks, in advance.

```
SELECT hotRods.Make, hotRods.Model, hotRods.Year, vertex.Make, vertex.Model, vertex.Year, hotRods.[Part #], vertex.[Part #]
FROM vertex 
FULL JOIN hotRods 
ON (vertex.Year = hotRods.Year) AND (hotRods.Model = vertex.Model) 
AND (vertex.Make = hotRods.Make) AND (RIGHT(hotRods.[Part #], 6) = RIGHT(vertex.[Part #],6));
```

Comment: MS Access doesn't support full outer join.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I write a full outer join query in access](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19615177/how-do-i-write-a-full-outer-join-query-in-access)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT hotRods.Make, hotRods.Model, hotRods.Year, vertex.Make, vertex.Model, vertex.Year, hotRods.[Part #], vertex.[Part #]
FROM vertex 
Left outer join hotRods 
ON (vertex.Year = hotRods.Year) AND (hotRods.Model = vertex.Model) 
AND (vertex.Make = hotRods.Make) AND (RIGHT(hotRods.[Part #], 6) = RIGHT (vertex.[Part #],6))
union 
SELECT hotRods.Make, hotRods.Model, hotRods.Year, vertex.Make, vertex.Model, vertex.Year, hotRods.[Part #], vertex.[Part #]
FROM vertex 
right outer join hotRods 
ON (vertex.Year = hotRods.Year) AND (hotRods.Model = vertex.Model) 
AND (vertex.Make = hotRods.Make) AND (RIGHT(hotRods.[Part #], 6) = RIGHT(vertex.[Part #],6))
```

Comment: it's a pleasure :)