# Access SQL Full Outer Join

Tags: sql, ms-access

Hi I was trying to Full Outer join two tables on access because I want to keep all items.

here is my code:

```
    SELECT aa.*, bb.firstname, bb.lastname, bb.totalcost
    FROM (select IT.*,HR.*from IT
    left join HR on HR.firstname=it.firstname and HR.lastname=IT.lastname)  
    AS 
    aa FULL OUTER JOIN 2016totalcost AS bb ON (bb.lastname=aa.IT.lastname) 
    AND (bb.firstname=aa.IT.firstname);
```

But I got error syntax error in from clause

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

NOTE:  The question was tagged Oracle when I answered.

The Oracle syntax would be:

```
select IT.*, HR.*, bb.firstname, bb.lastname, bb.totalcost
from IT left join
     HR
     on HR.firstname = it.firstname and HR.lastname = IT.lastname full outer join 
     2016totalcost tc 
     on tc.lastname = it.lastname and tc.firstname = it.firstname;
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, It works on Oracle. But I am not sure why I can not run it on access sql. but thank you at lease I have one solution

Comment: Oracle SQL differs from MS Access SQL differs from MySQL SQL differs from et cetera...

Answer (score 1):

Do a LEFT JOIN and UNION it to a RIGHT Join:

```
SELECT  * FROM Table1
              LEFT JOIN  Table2
    ON 
        Table1.joincolumn = Table2.joincolumn
UNION
SELECT * FROM Table1
             RIGHT JOIN Table2
    ON 
        Table1.joincolumn = Table2.joincolumn
```

#### Screenshot

Below you can see the result of an SQL statement similar to the one above.
Both tables are joined using `Table1.joinColumn = Table2.joinColumn`

- A and B are only in `T1`
- C and D are in both tables `T1` and `T2`
- E, F, and G are only in `T2`

[image: Access_Result_Left_Join_Union_Right_Join]

Answer (score 0):

Access does not recognize a Full Outer Join.

Here is an example of how to write the equivalent for MSA.

[How do I write a full outer join query in access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19615177/how-do-i-write-a-full-outer-join-query-in-access)