# Forcing NULL entries in ACCESS queries

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two ACCESS tables as follows

```
CustId  CustType
1        Silver
2          Gold
3          Gold
```

```
xDate   CustId  Value
01/01/2020  2   100
01/01/2020  1   50
02/02/2020  2   100
03/01/2020  2   200
03/01/2020  1   50
04/01/2020  2   100
04/01/2020  3   100
```

I would like to know the total spent between two dates for `Gold` customers and set up the following query:

```
SELECT a.CustId, SUM(t.Value) AS Total
FROM Transactions AS t 
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT CustId FROM Customers WHERE CustType = 'Gold'
) a 
ON a.CustId = t.CustId
WHERE t.xDate BETWEEN #2020/01/03# AND #2020/01/04# 
AND NOT a.CustId IS NULL
GROUP BY a.CustId;
```

This gives me the following:

```
2   300
3   100
```

If I change the query to `BETWEEN #2020/01/02# AND #2020/01/03#` I get this:

```
2   200
```

Everything is fine so far.  However, for the second query I would like to have the total transaction value for `Gold` customers as zero (or NULL) even if they have not spent anything during the period ie

```
2   200
3     0
```

I believe that I can do this in other dB's using `LEFT OUTER JOIN` but this is not available in ACCESS.  This post [How do I write a full outer join query in access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19615177/how-do-i-write-a-full-outer-join-query-in-access) suggests using `UNION`.  My attempt was

```
SELECT c.CustId, 0 as Total
FROM Customers c
WHERE c.CustType = 'Gold'
UNION
SELECT t.CustId, SUM(t.Value) AS Total
FROM Transactions t
WHERE t.xDate BETWEEN #2020/01/03# AND #2020/01/04# 
GROUP BY t.CustId;
```

but this produced the following results:

```
CustId  Total
1   50
2   0
2   200
3   0
```

This result contains all types of customer and has a duplicate for Customer 2.  I'm sure the answer is obvious if you know how but I just don't know how!  All suggestions gratefully received - thanks!

Comment: So, what will be your end result then?

Comment: Are dates in table international structure dd/mm/yyyy?

Comment: *...using LEFT OUTER JOIN but this is not available in ACCESS* of course it's available.

Comment: Harun24HR - please see OP
forpas - There seems to be a difference of opinion eg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49075392/access-sql-full-outer-join

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want all Gold customers, then `Customers` should be the first table in the `LEFT JOIN`.  There is also no need for a subquery on `customers`.  However, MS Access does want one on `Transactions`:

```
SELECT c.CustId, NZ(SUM(t.Value)) AS Total
FROM Customers as c LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT t.*
      FROM Transactions as t
      WHERE t.xDate BETWEEN #2020/01/03# AND #2020/01/04# 
     ) as t
     ON t.CustId = c.CustId
WHERE c.CustType = 'Gold'
GROUP BY c.CustId;
```

Comment: Hi  this gives the expected result when I change the date range to 2-3/1/2020 and is in a more understandable form (for me at least) than the other suggestions, so thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

***Edit:*** Simplified query

```
SELECT Customers.CustID, Sum(Transactions.tValue) AS Total
FROM Customers LEFT JOIN Transactions ON Customers.CustID = Transactions.CustID
WHERE (Transactions.xDate BETWEEN #2020/01/03# AND #2020/01/04#) AND (Customers.CustType='Gold')
GROUP BY Customers.CustID;
```

You can sum total of union query result group by customer id. try below

I assume your `CustID` field is `Number` data type. If it is string data type then you need to change `DLookup()` function criteria part like `DLookup("CustType","Customers","CustID='" & t.CustID & "'")`

```
SELECT ut.CustID, Sum(ut.Total) AS Total
FROM (SELECT c.CustId, 0 as Total, c.CustType
    FROM Customers AS c
    GROUP BY c.CustId,c.CustType

    UNION

    SELECT t.CustId, SUM(t.tValue) AS Total, DLookup("CustType","Customers","CustID=" & t.CustID ) as CustType
    FROM Transactions AS t
    WHERE t.xDate BETWEEN #2020/01/03# AND #2020/01/04# GROUP BY t.CustId)  AS ut GROUP BY ut.CustID, ut.CustType
HAVING (((ut.CustType)='gold'));
```

Comment: Note: `Value` is a reserve word for `MS-Access`. So, I have used `tValue` for transactions table.

Comment: Hi your original query gives the answer I was expecting (2 rows when I change the date range to 2-3/1/2020 - see OP) but the edited version only returns 1 row but thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

Query1:

```
SELECT CustId, SUM(Value) AS Total
FROM Transactions
WHERE xDate BETWEEN #2020/02/01# AND #2020/03/01#
GROUP BY CustId;
```

Query2:

```
SELECT Customers.CustID, Query1.Total
FROM Customers LEFT JOIN Query1 ON Customers.CustID = Query1.CustId
WHERE (((Customers.[CustType])="Gold"));
```

Answer (score 0):

`LEFT OUTER JOIN` is just called `LEFT JOIN` with Access-SQL, and works generally as expected.

See [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/left-join-right-join-operations-ebb18b36-7976-4c6e-9ea1-c701e9f7f5fb#:%7E:text=Use%20a%20LEFT%20JOIN%20operation,create%20a%20right%20outer%20join.) for more information on its usage and limitations.