# How can a select match each value only once?

Tags: sql, select, duplicates, full-outer-join

I'm matching amount values from `table1` and `table2`, tables having duplicates and different number of rows. Any amount can be matched only once (so not the way a standard select works) because total amount in the select for a table should remain the same as if I added all inserted values from that table.

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
    table1_amount int
);
INSERT INTO table1 (table1_amount)
VALUES
    (22),
    (11),
    (35),
    (45),
    (45),
    (65),
    (22),
    (22),
    (878),
    (56);

CREATE TABLE table2 (
    table2_amount int
);
INSERT INTO table2 (table2_amount)
VALUES
    (324),
    (43),
    (34),
    (35),
    (22),
    (22),
    (12),
    (35),
    (6);
```

A standard select would return 6 rows matching the three "22" from `table1` to the two "22" from `table2` (so every "22" from `table1` gets matched twice):

```
SELECT table1.table1_amount, table2.table2_amount
FROM table1 FULL OUTER JOIN table2 ON table1.table1_amount=table2.table2_amount;

table1_amount table2_amount
22 22
22 22
22 22
22 22
22 22
```

Now, I'd like to have only 2 matchings + 1 unmatched amount from `table1` so:

```
table1_amount table2_amount
22 22
22 22
22 NULL
```

How can you do that? I'm indicating here SQL but any solution (Excel, Access) would be good.

Comment: I think it will be difficult to generate your exact expected output based on the two tables you currently have.  But, do you really need this output?  Or, would you be OK with a report showing discrepancies in number of occurrences?

Comment: Which sql language are you using? add a tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this using `Row_Number()`:

```
with cte1 as
(Select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by table1_amount order by table1_amount) as ranking from table1),
 cte2 as
(Select *,ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by table2_amount order by table2_amount) as ranking from table2)
Select cte1.table1_amount, cte2.table2_amount from cte1 FULL OUTER JOIN cte2 on cte1.table1_amount = cte2.table2_amount and cte1.ranking = cte2.ranking
```

Comment: Works just fine as an SQL query - thanks a lot! Hmm, I'm trying to figure out how to use that query in MS Access, which does not support FULL OUTER JOIN -- any idea?

Comment: I have no experience in Access but [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19615177/9676724) might help

Comment: Thanks -- Also, Access doesn't support the WITH keyword... So I keep on digging :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

select cte1.table1_amount, cte2.table2_amount 
from (Select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by table1_amount order by table1_amount) as ranking from @table1) as cte1 
    left join (Select *,ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by table2_amount order by table2_amount) as ranking from @table2) as cte2 on cte1.table1_amount = cte2.table2_amount and cte1.ranking = cte2.ranking

Comment: Access signals "a syntax error, missing operator" here: `ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by table1_amount order by table1_amount) as ranking from @table1)`