# MS Access: Crosstab query on multiple tables (many-to-many relation)

Tags: ms-access

I’m working with a MS Access database.

I have three tables :

**Customers (idCustomer, CustomerName) :**

```
1   C1
2   C2
3   C3
4   C4
5   C5
```

**Products (idProduct, ProductName) :**

```
1   P1
2   P2
3   P3
4   P4
```

**Orders (id, idCustomer, idProduct, Quantity) :**

```
1   2   1   10
2   2   2   15
3   4   2   13
4   5   4   19
```

I’m working on a query to get this result :

- Rows = Customers (all customers)
- Columns = Products (all products)
- Cells = Quantity

**Like this :**

```
        P1      P2      P3      P4
C1      0       0       0       0
C2      10      15      0       0
C3      0       0       0       0
C4      0       13      0       0
C5      0       0       0       19
```

Can anyone help on this query task?

Comment: What did you try ? Where is the issue ?

Comment: Found the cross-tab query wizard?

Comment: I can't get all columns and all rows when I use cross-tab functionality (TRANSFORM PIVOT). I need to to get all the records of my tables customers and products, even the one without records in orders.

Comment: You are limited to 255 columns in Ms Access,if you have more products use Excel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trick is:

1. First build a regular SELECT query, joining the 3 tables, that returns the columns you want (CustomerName, ProductName, Quantity)
2. Then run the crosstab query wizard on this base query, it will be self-explanatory.

> I need to to get all the records of my tables customers and products, even the one without records in orders.

Then for the base query in 1. you need a [Full Outer Join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19615177/how-do-i-write-a-full-outer-join-query-in-access) .

Comment: Do you have an URL with an example ? I need to to get all the records of my tables customers and products, even the one without records in orders.

Answer (score 0):

select idcustomer,[1]as p1,[2] as p2,[3] as p3,[4] as p4
from (
select idcustomer ,idproduct,quantity from Orders)ps
pivot
(sum(Quantity)
For idproduct in  ([1],[2],[3],[4])
)
pv;
I am still not able to figure how to change the idcustomer to customername but this will help u(m sure for that!!).