# Convert Items stored in rows to columns (Huge data) - MS Access

Tags: ms-access

I have a table that have all company's product and the item each product include in the format below:

| Product ID | Item |
| --- | --- |
| Product 1 | Item 1 |
| Product 1 | Item 2 |
| Product 1 | Item 3 |
| Product 2 | Item 1 |
| Product 2 | Item 2 |
| Product 3 | Item 1 |
| Product 3 | Item 2 |
| Product 3 | Item 3 |

And so on.. (More than 2000 Products and each Product could have >70 items)

**I want it to be as:**

| Product ID | Item 1 | Item 2 | Item 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Product 1 | Item 1 | Item 2 | Item 3 |
| Product 2 | Item 1 | Item 2 |  |
| Product 3 | Item 1 | Item 2 | Item 3 |

And so on.. In separate cells

Note that I tried to use a combination of SQL queries and table manipulations (As below) but it give me error; **Too many crosstab column headers (2645)**.

`TRANSFORM First(Item) SELECT Product FROM MyTable GROUP BY Product PIVOT Item;`

Comment: To clarify, are you wanting data like this _in a report_ - or do you mean you actually want to restructure your database (storage) tables? If the latter, then that's a _very, very, very bad idea_ (because RDBMs databases do not work like this: [normalized records](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) are the fundamental basis for RDMBS, and having columns like that is the opposite of normalization...)

Comment: I do not want to restructure my DB, I just want to create a new table from an existing table.

Comment: You mean a `VIEW` - or a _table clone_?

Comment: Is there a maximum number of items that a product can include? What do you use to order the items within each product?

Comment: For TRANSFORM, you can have at least 3 column ``ProductId,Item,SomeValue``

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this?

Frustratingly, Access's SQL hasn't improved *at all* since its partial implementation of SQL-92 and doesn't support `FULL OUTER JOIN`, so I've implemented it using [a string of `UNION` queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19615177/how-do-i-write-a-full-outer-join-query-in-access)...

(Disclaimer: I don't have *access to* MS Access right now so I don't know if this query will work or not...)

```
SELECT
    ProductId,
    MAX( Item1 ) AS Item1,
    MAX( Item2 ) AS Item2,
    MAX( Item3 ) AS Item3
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            ProductId,
            MIN( Item ) AS Item1,
            NULL        AS Item2,
            NULL        AS Item3
        FROM
            ProductsTable
        WHERE
            Item = 'Item 1'
        GROUP BY
            ProductId

        UNION ALL

        SELECT
            ProductId,
            NULL        AS Item1,
            MIN( Item ) AS Item2,
            NULL        AS Item3
        FROM
            ProductsTable
        WHERE
            Item = 'Item 2'
        GROUP BY
            ProductId

        UNION ALL

        SELECT
            ProductId,
            NULL        AS Item1,
            NULL        AS Item2,
            MIN( Item ) AS Item3
        FROM
            ProductsTable
        WHERE
            Item = 'Item 3'
        GROUP BY
            ProductId
    ) AS q
GROUP BY
    q.ProductId

ORDER BY
    ProductId
```

Comment: MS Access does support [OUTER JOINS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/access/concepts/structured-query-language/perform-joins-using-access-sql#outer-joins) and has done so as long as I can remember

Comment: @JonathanWillcock I typo'd - I meant to say `FULL OUTER JOIN`, and [Access does not support them](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/join-tables-and-queries-3f5838bd-24a0-4832-9bc1-07061a1478f6#:~:text=This%20is%20called%20a%20full%20outer%20join%2C%20and%20Access%20doesn%E2%80%99t%20explicitly%20support%20them).

Comment: Assuming all his products have at least one item, then you don't need a `FULL OUTER JOIN`; you can get there with `LEFT OUTER JOIN`s

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your Products table actually has IDs (eg integer) for Product and Items as well as Names (text), you can in fact construct a view using left joins.  Something like this:

```
SELECT p1.ProductName, p1.ItemName AS [Item 1], p2.ItemName AS [Item 2], p3.ItemName AS [Item 3]
FROM (Products AS p1 
LEFT JOIN Products AS p2 ON (p1.ProductId = p2.ProductId AND p2.ItemId = 2))
LEFT JOIN Products AS p3 ON (p1.ProductId = p3.ProductId AND p3.ItemId = 3)
WHERE p1.ItemId = 1
ORDER BY p1.ProductId;
```

You will need to add as many left joins as you have potential items minus one.  The assumption here is that all products have at least one item!

Answer (score 0):

Access `Transform` requery 3 columns for transformation.

We can add third column by subquery.

Query

```
TRANSFORM First(qrProduct.[ItemV]) AS [First-ItemV]
SELECT qrProduct.[ProductId]
FROM (
   SELECT Product.ProductId, Product.Item
          , Product.Item as  ItemV
   FROM Product
)qrProduct
GROUP BY qrProduct.[ProductId]
PIVOT qrProduct.[Item];
```

output is what you want with test data above.

But your problem is some another (Too many crosstab column headers (2645)).
Probably, your table is like

| ProductID | Item |
| --- | --- |
| Product 1 | Item 1-1 |
| Product 1 | Item 1-2 |
| Product 1 | Item 1-3 |
| Product 2 | Item 2-1 |
| Product 2 | Item 2-2 |
| Product 3 | Item 3-1 |
| Product 3 | Item 3-2 |

There we add column row_number() - "ItemN.." for pivot. Crosstab column count is limited to max.number of items for ProductId ( not values)

```
TRANSFORM First(qrProductRanged.[Item]) AS [Min-Item]
SELECT qrProductRanged.[ProductId]
FROM 
 ( SELECT Product.ProductId, Product.Item
         ,'ItemN' &  count(*)   as rn
   FROM Product LEFT JOIN Product as Product_1 
     ON Product_1.ProductId = Product.ProductId 
           and Product_1.Item <= Product.Item 
   GROUP By Product.ProductId,Product.Item
 )as  qrProductRanged
GROUP BY qrProductRanged.[ProductId]
PIVOT qrProductRanged.[rn];
```

Subquery gets

| ProductId | rn | Item |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Product 1 | ItemN1 | Item 1-1 |
| Product 1 | ItemN2 | Item 1-2 |
| Product 1 | ItemN3 | Item 1-3 |
| Product 2 | ItemN1 | Item 2-1 |
| Product 2 | ItemN2 | Item 2-2 |
| Product 3 | ItemN1 | Item 3-1 |
| Product 3 | ItemN2 | Item 3-2 |

And final output

| ProductId | ItemN1 | ItemN2 | ItemN3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Product 1 | Item 1-1 | Item 1-2 | Item 1-3 |
| Product 2 | Item 2-1 | Item 2-2 |  |
| Product 3 | Item 3-1 | Item 3-2 |  |